# Ruby on Rails 3 : "superclass mismatch for class ..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Platform: Mac OSX 10.6

In my terminal, i start the Ruby console with "rails c"

While following the Ruby on Rails 3 tutorial to build a class:

```
class Word < String 
  def palindrome? #check if a string is a palindrome
    self == self.reverse
  end
end
```

i get the error message:

```
TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Word
    from (irb):33
    from /Users/matthew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /Users/matthew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/matthew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

The tutorial shows that it has no problem and i know the code is fine; I've searched other related questions, but they all involved migrating from Ruby 2 to 3 or erb vs eruby.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You already have a `Word` class defined elsewhere. I tried within a Rails 3 app but was not able to replicate.

If you have not created a second `Word` class yourself, it is likely one of your Gems or plugins already defines it.

Comment: Thanks, i ended up restarting the console. Earlier, i did use a different class name, yet got the same error.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about gems or plugins probably aready defining the class. Had the problem in a JRuby 1.7.1 application in my PagesController. Renaming it solved the issue.

Comment: But the problem in not the existence of the class itself, but that it has different parent class.

Comment: restarting the console worked for me as well @Matthew

Answer (score 27):

This can also happen as such:

```
# /models/document/geocoder.rb
class Document
  module Geocoder
  end
end

# /models/document.rb
require 'document/geocoder'

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Geocoder
end
```

The require loads `Document` (which has a superclass of Object) before `Document < ActiveRecord::Base` (which has a different superclass).

I should note that in a Rails environment the require is not usually needed since it has auto class loading.

Answer (score 23):

I had the problem with a Rails 4 application. I used concerns under the user namespace.

```
class User
  module SomeConcern
  end
end
```

In development everything worked fine but in production (I guess because of preload_app true) I got the mismatch error. The fix was pretty simple. I just added an initializer:

```
require "user"
```

Cheers!

Comment: That's the most frustrating thing for me! Wish I could upvote it more!

Comment: I also have this problem, can you tell me where `require 'user'` added?

Comment: @JeskTop just add a new file to `config/initializers` with just that single file. Initializers run before the whole application gets loaded and make sure that the model class gets loaded first.

Comment: @2called-chaos Thanks, but it still not work for me. I add a question, but no one can help me fix this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795339/why-i-use-rails-model-concerns-will-get-the-superclass-mismatch-errors-with-clas

Comment: This solved my problem, however I am not sure why I have this problem. I have 2 models order.rb and notification.rb and nowhere in my app is any other Order of Notification class

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it's worth commenting that you don't think it's the best solution as per the discussion [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14401#issuecomment-251125494): _"That's very bad advice, you should not require something that is meant to be autoloaded, much less in an initializer."_

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes we 'open class' without us knowing. For example with some deep module nesting:

```
# space_gun.rb
class SpaceGun << Weapon
  def fire
    Trigger.fire
  end
end

# space_gun/trigger.rb
class SpaceGun
  class Trigger
  end
end
```

When we define trigger, we open the existing SpaceGun class. This works.
However if we load the two file in the reverse order, the error would be raised, because we would define a SpaceGun class first, but is not a Weapon.

Sometimes we make this mistake because we explicitly require sub module (e.g. trigger) from the parent class. Which means the class definition will be done the reverse order, causing this issue.

```
# surely nothing can go wrong if we require what we need first right?
require 'space_gun/trigger'
class SpaceGun << Weapon
  def fire
    Trigger.fire
  end
end
# BOOM
```

Either

1. rely on auto loading
2. always put inheritance to every open class occurrence.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem right now. Basically that means that Word is defined as a class elsewhere and my guess is that it's on the rail-ties gem. Just change Word to Word2 and it should work fine on the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your specific case, any of the already-provided answers could be your solution.

To find out quickly and easily, temporarily set `config.eager_load = true` and start your rails console. It should immediately fail with a more explicit error message, pointing at the right file and line number.

Don't forget to set `config.eager_load` back to its original value after.

Comment: In my case eager loading actually solved the problem. I did not get a more detailed error message after enabling it. Interesting… (Maybe it lead to both occurrences being loaded in reverse order and one occurrence did not explicitly declare a superclass?)

Comment: @einjohn This means you need to check on your inclusions, you are certainly missing one somewhere