# chef/knife (ruby) error: superclass mismatch for class Edit (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, chef-infra, knife

i am using `bundler` to handle ruby gems dependencies. i require the gems using `bundler` programatically.

when i try to invoke `knife` programatically, which its dependency is specified within the `Gemfile` i get en error. i execute `knife` as follows:

```
Chef::Knife.run ["-v"] #invoking knife
```

and it returns the following error:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.6.2/lib/chef/knife/edit.rb:5:in `<class:Knife>': superclass mismatch for class Edit (TypeError)
```

i am familiar with [Ruby on Rails 3 : "superclass mismatch for class ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512023/ruby-on-rails-3-superclass-mismatch-for-class) and the reason this occurs. but there is nothing i do which coincide with the explanation within the aforementioned stackoverflow post.

can somebody shed the light on the issue and a resolution for it?

Comment: try `gem uninstall knife-essentials` and let me know if problem persist still.

Comment: @Gopalrathore, indeed solves the problem. how did you know which ruby gem causes the conflict? (how do i mark this as "solved"?)

Comment: when I was searching for this problem, I have got this issue fix from the developers of this gem in a technical conversation. I will add it as an answer if it solves ur issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this [Edit class](https://github.com/jkeiser/knife-essentials/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/edit_essentials.rb#L6) is creating the issue, and `uninstalling` knife-essentials gem will solve your problem.

**Try it once:**

```
gem uninstall knife-essentials
```

Answer (score 5):

You are right, that's the related error.

`class Edit` was already defined somewhere else with a different superclass from the one is trying to use now.

Simple test on irb/pry

```
[56] pry(main)> class Comida; end

[57] pry(main)> class Comida < Integer; end

TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Comida
from (pry):53:in `__pry__'
```

So you should post/check what exactly are you requiring with bundler programatically and how. Why not use a `Gemfile` and then `bundle exec` to run your script? Let bundler handle dependencies for you, if you did this programatically because you are concerned on how and when are the gems required you can add `required: false` to avoid the automatic behavior and do yourself the requires when needed, i.e.

Change this `Gemfile`

```
gem 'chef-solo'
gem 'knife-solo'
```

To this:

```
gem 'chef-solo', require: false
gem 'knife-solo', require: false
```

Then manually in your code perform the requires when you fit necessary and take back the control you needed:

```
# ... code ....
require 'chef-solo'

# ... more code ...
require 'knife-solo'
```

### There are, at least, 3 ways to debug this:

#### 1) Plain old ruby debug

To [debug](http://elgalu.github.io/2013/console-ruby-debug-is-easy/) this you can set a breakpoint at that offending line:

```
$ ruby -r debug your_program.rb

# Set a breakpoint where problem arises
break /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.6.2/lib/chef/knife/edit.rb:5

# Set a poor-man debug `puts` to find out where is a class defined
class Object
  def self.inherited(klass)
    targets = %w(Edit Chef::Knife::Edit)
    puts "#{klass.name} defined at #{__FILE__}:#{__LINE__}" if targets.include?(klass.name)
  end
end

# Now run until program ends or hits that breakpoint
cont

# Once it hits the breakpoing program will pause there and you can play around but the previus `puts` should already have showed where the `Edit` class is first defined.

#=> Chef::Knife::Edit defined at /some/pissing/file:432
```

#### 2) With gem pry

You could also use `pry.binding` to stop the program at that line and look around to see what's happening by temporary editing `edit.rb`

```
$ vim /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.6.2/lib/chef/knife/edit.rb + 5

# Add this code before the offending line:
require 'pry'
binding.pry
```

Will also need to include `gem "pry"` in your `Gemfile` for that to work and run the program with `bundle exec` don't forget.

Program will stop there (at the line `binding.pry`) before continuing and then you can use pry goodness to find out where that class was already defined

```
[1] pry(main)> ? Bundler
#=> From: .../gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb @ line 9

[2] pry(main)> ? Chef::Knife::Edit
#=> From: xxxxxxx.rb @ line xx
```

#### 3) With gem pry-rescue

Also there is [pry-rescue](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/pry-rescue) gem which will "start a pry session whenever something goes wrong"

```
$ gem install pry-rescue pry-stack_explorer
$ rescue your_program.rb
```

Or, if running your program through `bundle exec` add this to your `Gemfile`

```
group :development do
  gem 'pry-rescue'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
end
```

And the program will enter a pry session whenever an exception is raised!

Sorry for giving so many options, hope one helps!

Comment: No, these types of answers: detailed and well-formed - are exactly what it should be. +1

Comment: wow! thanks for spending your time and share your knowledge. it does not solves the issue depicted above, but reveals why it occurs. and once again, thank you.