# Superclass mismatch for class

Tags: ruby

When I wrote the following code, it runs normally:

```
class Application
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

class Email2 < Application
end
```

But when I changed `Email2` to `Email` like this:

```
class Application
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

class Email < Application
end
```

I got the error message: `superclass mismatch for class Email`. Please help me.

Comment: where are you coding..? I mean in the console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails 3 : "superclass mismatch for class ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512023/ruby-on-rails-3-superclass-mismatch-for-class)

Comment: i code on firefox browser? I code online on web

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Email` class must already be defined somewhere else.

You can test that by using the `defined?` method like this:

```
defined?(Email)
```

Think about namespacing your code by using a module:

```
module MyNameSpace
  class MyClass
  end
end
```

Looks like you need to remove the definition from the CodeAcademy Context. Try deleting your browser cookies and refreshing the page.

Comment: When i add "defined?(Email)" at the end of my code, it print out ""constant" 
But that is studying website, and that is a problem which i must resolve.

That is my mission:
"Create a second class, Email, that inherits from Message. Give it its own initialize method that takes just one parameter, subject, and has one instance variable, @subject, set equal to subject."

How to resolve it? I want to jump to next lesion ?

Comment: Can you send me the link to the lesson?

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/courses/ruby-beginner-en-MFiQ6/3/4?curriculum_id=5059f8619189a5000201fbcb

But i think you must start from the beginning. Thanks u

Comment: @Viet note that your `Email` class does not inherit from `Message`

Comment: My mission is: "create Email class inherits from Message"
When i add a line like: "module ...", my problem still not resolved

Comment: @Viet that's [Nesting](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Nesting), [Inheritance](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Inheritance) works like this: `class Email < Message`

Comment: I think that is bug of this website.
I can't pass this lesion.

Comment: I think you are right. I have used code academy in the past and the problem is that code is not unloaded for every lesson. So the problem is that there is an Email class defined there already. So check out my updated answer (in a minute)

Comment: @Viet, I think you can just refresh the page to clear the Email definition from the context.

Comment: @jphager: thanks you so much. When I clear cookies and refresh my page, it can run normally.

Answer (score 4):

The error occurs because there's already a class `Email` defined somewhere else, that inherits from something else than `Application`.

When using the `class` keyword, if the class already exists ruby will try to reopen the class, allowing you to add things to the existing class definition.

If you write `class Email < Application`, ruby will try to make `Email` inherit from `Application`. Ruby classes can't have more than one parent class, so if the existing `Email` class already inherits from something else, you will get this error.

To inherit from `Message`, you write this: `class Email < Message`

Comment: Yes, i have changed it from "Application" to "Message"
And i understand why that bug is occurred.

But i was studying on http://codecademy.com website. I don't know how must i do to pass this lesion:

"Create a second class, Email, that inherits from Message. Give it its own initialize method that takes just one parameter, subject, and has one instance variable, @subject, set equal to subject.""

Comment: @Viet Perhaps this is not the correct forum to ask for solutions to study material. Maybe you should read up on Ruby basics a bit.