# Ruby on rails server command mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew, rbenv

I'm trying to install ruby on rails following this guide: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.12-sierra

It works correct, but at the end when I try the command "rails server", the following error shows up and I can't run my application.

```
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_CERT_REVOKED
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_INVALID_CA
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_PATH_LENGTH_EXCEEDED
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_INVALID_PURPOSE
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_CERT_UNTRUSTED
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_CERT_REJECTED
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_SUBJECT_ISSUER_MISMATCH
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_AKID_SKID_MISMATCH
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_AKID_ISSUER_SERIAL_MISMATCH
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_KEYUSAGE_NO_CERTSIGN
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_APPLICATION_VERIFICATION
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_IGNORE_CRITICAL
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_X509_STRICT
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_ALLOW_PROXY_CERTS
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_POLICY_CHECK
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_EXPLICIT_POLICY
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_INHIBIT_ANY
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_INHIBIT_MAP
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_NOTIFY_POLICY
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_EXTENDED_CRL_SUPPORT
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_USE_DELTAS
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_CHECK_SS_SIGNATURE
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_TRUSTED_FIRST
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_NO_ALT_CHAINS
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SSL_CLIENT
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SSL_SERVER
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_NS_SSL_SERVER
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SMIME_SIGN
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_SMIME_ENCRYPT
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_CRL_SIGN
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_ANY
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_OCSP_HELPER
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::PURPOSE_TIMESTAMP_SIGN
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_COMPAT
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_SSL_CLIENT
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_SSL_SERVER
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_EMAIL
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_OBJECT_SIGN
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_OCSP_SIGN
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_OCSP_REQUEST
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::TRUST_TSA
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_AREA
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_DIR
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_DIR_ENV
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE_ENV
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_PRIVATE_DIR
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_INTERNALERROR
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_MALFORMEDREQUEST
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_NOSTATUS
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_SIGREQUIRED
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_SUCCESSFUL
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_TRYLATER
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_AFFILIATIONCHANGED
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_CACOMPROMISE
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_CERTIFICATEHOLD
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_CESSATIONOFOPERATION
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_KEYCOMPROMISE
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_REMOVEFROMCRL
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_SUPERSEDED
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_UNAUTHORIZED
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::REVOKED_STATUS_UNSPECIFIED
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOCERTS
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOINTERN
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOSIGS
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOCHAIN
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOVERIFY
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOEXPLICIT
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOCASIGN
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NODELEGATED
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOCHECKS
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::TRUSTOTHER
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPID_KEY
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOTIME
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_CERTSTATUS_GOOD
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_CERTSTATUS_REVOKED
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_CERTSTATUS_UNKNOWN
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_RESPID_NAME
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_RESPID_KEY
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_RSA
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_DSA
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_DH
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_RAND
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_CIPHERS
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_DIGESTS
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_ALL
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_NONE
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::UNIVERSAL_TAG_NAME
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::EOC
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::BOOLEAN
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::INTEGER
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::BIT_STRING
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::OCTET_STRING
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::NULL
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::OBJECT
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::OBJECT_DESCRIPTOR
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::EXTERNAL
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::REAL
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::ENUMERATED
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::EMBEDDED_PDV
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::UTF8STRING
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::RELATIVE_OID
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::SEQUENCE
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::SET
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::NUMERICSTRING
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::PRINTABLESTRING
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::T61STRING
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::VIDEOTEXSTRING
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::IA5STRING
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::UTCTIME
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::GENERALIZEDTIME
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::GRAPHICSTRING
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::ISO64STRING
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::GENERALSTRING
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::UNIVERSALSTRING
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::CHARACTER_STRING
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::BMPSTRING
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/pkey.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::DH::DEFAULT_1024
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/pkey.rb:8: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_1024 was here
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/pkey.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::DH::DEFAULT_2048
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/pkey.rb:17: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_2048 was here
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/pkey.rb:30: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::DEFAULT_TMP_DH_CALLBACK
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/pkey.rb:30: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_TMP_DH_CALLBACK was here
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of AES was here
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::CAST5
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of CAST5 was here
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::BF
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of BF was here
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::DES
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of DES was here
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::IDEA
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of IDEA was here
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC2
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC2 was here
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC4
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC4 was here
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC5
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC5 was here
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES128 was here
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES192
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES192 was here
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.0.3/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES256 was here
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64:in `<class:Cipher>': superclass mismatch for class Cipher (TypeError)
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:16:in `<module:OpenSSL>'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.rb:17:in `require'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails.rb:11:in `require'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in `require'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in `require_command!'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:83:in `server'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lechucico/Documents/myapp/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/lechucico/Documents/myapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/lechucico/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/lechucico/Documents/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

What I could do?

Thanks.

Comment: From [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512023/ruby-on-rails-3-superclass-mismatch-for-class), it looks like you have the Class `Cipher` in your code (or gems) twice. Do you have any custom code or custom gems that the guide didn't tell you to include? Try running `bundle install` or `bundle update`.

Comment: I've just followed the guide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I solved it by uninstalling that particular version of openssl. Try

```
gem uninstall openssl -v 2.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

There could actually be multiple sub reasons for the issue, but clearly the main issue here is that your code is initialising openssl library more than once. This issue is also posted and discussed about on [openssl git repo](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/issues/103).

Referencing to the linked article above I would suggest two solutions (mainly workarounds) to this.
 1. Downgrade your version of openssl, to probably 2.0.2
 2. Try adding the following code at the top of your code:

```
if defined?(RUBY_DESCRIPTION) && RUBY_DESCRIPTION.start_with?("ruby 2.4")
  gem "openssl"
end
```

Cause of this error seems to be a third party gem issue, instead of openssl itself. Might be, multiple gems are using the same library with different versions and are loading the library twice. I suggest you have a look at the gems that you are using and their respective dependencies.